# C# List of properties. Need to group them based on 2 conditions

Tags: c#, linq, collections, grouping

I have a List of database data in which 2 properties are important to group on.   I stripped out the non-important properties and created a List of the data in which it needs to be sorted.

Not sure if some method with algorithm with linq statement should be done,  and then how would it be best to store the results?

```
public class PaymentVouchers
{
    public string PayFromBankAccountId {get; set; }
    public int PaymentType {get; set;}
    public decimal TotalPaymentAmount {get; set;}
}
```

Data:

```
var paymentVouchers = new List<PaymentVouchers>()
{
    new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "ABC", PaymentType = 5},
    new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "ABC", PaymentType = 5},
    new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "ABC", PaymentType = 5},
    new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "ABC", PaymentType = 6},
    new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "ABC", PaymentType = 6},
    new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "ABC", PaymentType = 6},
    new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "DEF", PaymentType = 5},
    new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "DEF", PaymentType = 5},
    new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "DEF", PaymentType = 6},
    new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "DEF", PaymentType = 6},
}
```

Thus from the data,  I need to group  ABC and 5   together as there are 3 of those , then group together ABC and 6  , there are also 3 of those by chance.   Then in the data 2 other groups are seen     DEF and 5  - 2 of those  and DEF and 6  , there are 2 of those.

So if I did a foreach loop,  a linq statement  - How do I keep them from getting messy with grouping them into what type of collection ?   Hashset of Tuples ?   Some new List with a new property that is an identifier "key"  .  Performance is ideal

Thoughts?

Additions: update:

I'm having trouble putting that data in the list into a new list

```
var paymentGroups = new List<PaymentGroups>();



paymentGroups = paymentVouchers.GroupBy(x => new { x.PayFromBankAccountId, x.PaymentType })
.Select(x => new
{
    x.Key.PayFromBankAccountId,
    x.Key.PaymentType,
    //x.Sum(PaymentType)
    Sum = x.Sum(TotalPaymentAmount),
    paymentGroups.TotalCount = x.Key.Count 
});


paymentGroups.Dump();
```

}

public class PaymentGroups
{

```
public string PayFromBankAccountId { get; set; }
public int PaymentType { get; set; }
public decimal TotalAmounts { get; set; }
public int TotalCount {get; set; }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ValueTuple` for grouping. It's hard to compete with its performance characteristics. Note that `LINQ` is not ideal for performance.

```cs
List<(string Group, int Total, int Amount)> data = paymentVouchers
    .GroupBy(v => (v.PayFromBankAccountId, v.PaymentType))
    .Select(g => (g.Key, Vouchers: g.ToList()))
    .Select(t => (Group: $"{t.Key.PayFromBankAccountId}|{t.Key.PaymentType}", Total: t.Vouchers.Count, Amount: t.Vouchers.Sum(x => x.PaymentType)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I added to my question.   I have a List that I would like to use to store the groups with total count,  total amounts and the other values .   How can I achieve this ?   So var Groups  - say that was set to be that new List PaymentGroups  that I would like to hydrate with the group results?

Comment: I believe you are looking for `g.ToList()`. It's a bit hidden. Please try the new code above. It's a good start.

Comment: I see ,  so then I could have my new List replace this on the fly List "data"   ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 properties on group by like this:

```
paymentVouchers.GroupBy(x => new { x.PayFromBankAccountId, x.PaymentType }).Select(x => new {
  x.Key.PayFromBankAccountId,
  x.Key.PaymentType,
  x.Sum(/*Something*/)
  // REST
})
```

EDIT:

```
paymentGroups = paymentVouchers.GroupBy(x => new { x.PayFromBankAccountId, x.PaymentType })
.Select(x => new 
{
    x.Key.PayFromBankAccountId,
    x.Key.PaymentType,
    TotalAmounts = x.Sum(TotalPaymentAmount),
    TotalCount = x.Count() 
});
```

This will return a list grouped by 2 keys and their value and sum of TotalPaymentAmount for each group and count of each group.

If you want to put in your defined class then:

```
paymentGroups = paymentVouchers.GroupBy(x => new { x.PayFromBankAccountId, x.PaymentType })
.Select(x => new PaymentGroups
{
    PayFromBankAccountId = x.Key.PayFromBankAccountId,
    PaymentType = x.Key.PaymentType,
    TotalAmounts = x.Sum(TotalPaymentAmount),
    TotalCount = x.Count() 
});
```

Comment: That does group them, thank you for that.   However - how could I then store them into some collection in which I would then know the number count of each ,  and then yes that 3rd property will end up showing an $ amount in which i can that know the total for each grouping.    Currently that Linq statement spits out the distinct groups if i set it to   var blah = your code       -  but how can i count how many there are and then place that in some collection ?

Comment: Oh, I see a Sum ... hmm  so if I created some new list to hold thing values ...

Comment: If you want the count inside the collection. You can just change the x.Sum(/*something*/) with
Count = x.Count()

Comment: Or for sum of the collection you can do "Sum = x.Sum(TotalPaymentAmount)"

Comment: I added to the question a new class with properties , and I'm trying to understand how to pump the data into that list  -  notice i'm using your statement, but having trouble with Sum and matching on the different types  and the anonymous types etc..

Comment: Checked the edited answer. @JeremyMiller

Comment: Last one is what you need I think. @JeremyMiller

Comment: It doesn't like this       TotalAmounts = x.Sum(TotalPaymentAmount),      - i tried adding it to the   new { ...   as  x....      but it doesn't like it

Comment: If this solved your problem can you mark me as accepted answer?

Comment: CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<UserQuery.PaymentGroups>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<UserQuery.PaymentGroups>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: I plan to mark your answer as correct - but having a few issues  , that error above and that Sum(TotalPaymentAmount)  it is not liking    thx again

Comment: Ok , I added a  ToList() that fixed that first error ,  but how do I do a Sum of the TotalPaymentAmount  ?    It doesn't like it..    I added  to the new part ,  added x to both places .. still it doesn't like it